# Can I optimize area of cylinder with no givens?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a problem which should be very easy (as the rest of them are on this worksheet) but this one has me stumped. The question reads:

> A metal can is in the form of a cylinder. It has a bottom but no top. The surface area is a constant *S* square meters. Find the dimensions of the can which maximize the volume.

For the surface area of a cylinder, I know the equation is $2\pi rh + 2\pi r^2$. Since we have no top of the can, the formula changes to $2\pi rh + \pi r^2$. The volume of a cylinder is $V=\pi r^2h$.

In all of the other problems on the sheet we've basically solved for one variable like r or h using a given surface area or volume. This problem, however says the surface area is $S$ instead of actually giving a numeric value.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Since you are given the surface area, $S$, you can use that to eliminate either $h$ or $r$.

Comment: Makes no difference, instead of a number for the area, like $17$, use $S$.

Comment: You'll probably obtain a ratio between $r$ and $h$, like $r=h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equation

> $$ S= 2\pi r h + \pi r^2 $$

to get $h$ as

> $$ h=\frac{S-\pi r^2 }{2\pi r } $$

then substitute in the volume equation V for $h$ to get an equation in $r$

> $$ V(r) = \pi r^2 \left(\frac{S-\pi r^2 }{2\pi r } \right) $$

and then use derivative techniques to maximize.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this. It makes so much more sense now.

Comment: Sometimes we miss things. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

Since the surface area is $S$,
from your formula,
$S
=2\pi rh+\pi r^2
$.
From this,
you can solve for either
$r$ or $h$ as a function
of $S$ and the other dimension.

It would probably be easiest
to solve for $h$
as a function of $S$ and $r$
since $h$ occurs linearly.

Now,
substitute the formula for $h$
into the equation for $V$.
This will be an expression involving
$S$ and $r$.
You want to find
the value of $r$
that maximizes this expression,
since that will produce
the largest volume.